# Is there a way to display the first two results of each unique id?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, greatest-n-per-group

I work in healthcare. In a Postgres database, we have a table member IDs and dates. I'm trying to pull the latest two dates for each member ID.

Simplified sample data:

```
A 1
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 5
C 7
D 1
D 2
D 3
D 4
```

Desired result:

```
A 1
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 5
D 1
D 2
```

Comment: Your sample suggests gap-less, unique, 1-based serial numbers per ID. Is that so? Please be clear. And always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: Hey Erwin, this is just sample data (I work in healthcare).  The Letter Column are populated with different member IDs and the Number Column is populated with different dates.  I'm trying to find a way to pull the latest two dates from each member ID

Comment: Do you need the latest two *rows* or the the latest two *dates* (can be more than two rows)? Is the table big? Roughly how many rows per ID? These details matter (a lot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I get a strong feeling this is for a homework assignment and would recommend that you look into partitioning and specifically rank() function by yourself first before looking at my solution.
- Moreover, you have not specified how you received the initial result you provided, so I'll have to assume you just did `select letter_column, number_column from my_table;` to achieve the result.

So, what you actually want here is partition the initial query result into groups by the `letter_column` and select the first two rows in each. rank() function lets you assign each row a number, counting within groups:

```
select letter_column,
   number_column,
   rank() over (partition by letter_column order by number_column) as rank
from my_table;
```

Since it's a function, you can't use it in a predicate in the same query, so you'll have to build another query around this one, this time filtering the results where `rank` is over 2:

```
with ranked_results as (select letter_column,
                           number_column,
                           rank() over (partition by letter_column order by number_column asc) as rank
                    from my_table mt)
select letter_column,
       number_column
from ranked_results
where rank < 3;
```

Here's an SQLFiddle to play around: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e90744/1/0

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Yevgeniy!

Thanks for getting back to me.  I can see how this looks like a homework assignment but I assure you its not.  I work in healthcare so I can't use sample data from my work due to HIPPA.  But yes I'm essentially running a query where I pull member IDs (letter column) and their eligibility dates (number column), but I only need the latest two for each ID and some can have several different ones. 

Thanks for showing me the rank function I'll try to see if I can get it to work!

Comment: For the top two just make sure you use order by <column> desc in you partition by clause